# Award Budget Cuts (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

This was a problem on Pramp. The question:

> The awards committee of your alma mater (i.e. your college/university) asked for your assistance with a budget allocation problem they’re facing. Originally, the committee planned to give N research grants this year. However, due to spending cutbacks, the budget was reduced to newBudget dollars and now they need to reallocate the grants. The committee made a decision that they’d like to impact as few grant recipients as possible by applying a maximum cap on all grants. Every grant initially planned to be higher than cap will now be exactly cap dollars. Grants less or equal to cap, obviously, won’t be impacted.
>
> Given an array grantsArray of the original grants and the reduced
> budget newBudget, write a function findGrantsCap that finds in the
> most efficient manner a cap such that the least number of recipients
> is impacted and that the new budget constraint is met (i.e. sum of the
> N reallocated grants equals to newBudget).
>
> Analyze the time and space complexities of your solution.

This is what my solution looks like, in PHP.

```
$grantsArray = [61, 56, 87, 93, 55, 27];
$newBudget = 170;

function findGrantsCap($grantsArray, $newBudget) : array {
  $newArray = [];
  foreach($grantsArray as $entry) {
    if(!($entry <= $newBudget / count($grantsArray))) {
      array_push($newArray, $newBudget / count($grantsArray));
    } else {
      array_push($newArray, $entry);
    }
  }
  return $newArray;
}

print_r(findGrantsCap($grantsArray, $newBudget));
```

This was my first attempt and it worked. However, I think this could have been solved better.

Is there anything I could do to improve my code? Thanks!

Comment: You may be interested in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try and reduce the repetition of calculations, so the maximum budget can be worked out before the `foreach` loop.  Also rather than have an `if` to check if it's above this value, then use `min` to take the lowest of the entry and the maximum budget

```
function findGrantsCap($grantsArray, $newBudget) : array {
    $maxBudget = $newBudget / count($grantsArray);
    $newArray = [];
    foreach($grantsArray as $entry) {
        $newArray[] = min ( $entry, $maxBudget);
    }
    return $newArray;
}
```